# Clash of Clans, playing with a rushed Town Hall and no defence upgrades. What does matchmaking take into account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I hear that the game has updated the matchmaking algorithm so that rushing is less punished now, but not that much detail regarding this.

If I rush my Town Hall, I will pretty much have no defence upgrades, and although I may have some army upgrades, it’s certainly not going to be as strong as most people with the same Town Hall level. So when I go to play matches my stats are just going to be inherently lower.

Does the game now take into account how much combat power you actually have? How bad does the rushed Town Hall level still affect matchmaking and resources gainable/losable?

Comment: as far as i'm aware matchmaking is just done based on trophy level but i have absolutely zero source to back that up